# Problems using webcam in python + openCV

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

I am using the following code to access my webcam using openCV + python...

```
import cv

cv.NamedWindow('webcam_feed', cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

cam = cv.CaptureFromCAM(-1)
```

I am then getting the following error in the console...

```
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
```

I was originally using,

```
cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
```

to access the same and had the same issue and used -1 because it is suppose to pick up any webcam.

I also tested to see if Ubuntu recognizes the webcam and it does. I am using v4l2 for the webcam.

{EDIT}

I am using the following code to display a video feed, it seems to only be showing just one image the web cam captured instead of a continuous video feed...

```
import cv
cv.NamedWindow('webcam_feed', cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
cam = cv.CaptureFromCAM(-1)
feed = cv.QueryFrame(cam)
cv.ShowImage("webcam_feed", feed)
cv.WaitKey(-1)
```

Comment: I get the same error, but it's working fine. I get proper image output from the webcam.

Is your webcam working properly ? Do you get the proper image ?

Comment: Same for me. But as Froyo mentioned, it works fine and get proper images. Do you get it?

Comment: Okay it is showing up in the window I created... But a new problem has occurred, please see the edits I made to the original post...

Comment: This was the exact same problem which showed up (after reinstallation) one night before my Engg final year project. I wrote another script that would capture the image and send it across to OpenCV. :P

Answer (score 1):

WOW, answered my own question in 15 after me posting this. I did some research and the reason for the web cam only grabbing one image is because of the...

```
cv.WaitKey(-1)
```

This doesn't allow the contents of the window to refresh. I set the number to 10...

```
cv.WaitKey(10)
```

and it worked beautifully. I also tried 100, but saw no difference. I only saw a difference when the number was 1000. I use 1 because seems that it runs the smoothest.

Here is the full code to display a web cam feed

```
import cv

cv.NamedWindow("webcam", 1)

cam = cv.CaptureFromCAM(-1)

While True:
feed = cv.QueryFrame(cam)
cv.ShowImage("webcam", feed)
cv.WaitKey(1)
```

Comment: can it be that you need the 2 lines bellow the while block indented? cv.WaitKey waits for you to press a key

Comment: This does not seem to fix the printing of `VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument`. Did you fix that in the end?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to put

```
frame = cv.QueryFrame(cam)
cv.ShowImage("Webcam Feed", frame)
```

in a loop to continuously update the image shown in the window.  That is, the frame from `cv.QueryFrame` is a static image, not a continuous video.

If you want to be able to exit with a key press, test `cv.WaitKey` with a small timeout in the loop too.

Comment: Thank you, I actually just figured it out after digging through some examples... I really appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the command in root

xhost +

save my time, Note to close and open new terminal.

See you.