# opencv alternative for capturing webcam picture

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a webcam (Logitech, C200) and want to try to get pictures from it directly into c++.

I try this code

```
 CvCapture* capture;
 capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( 0 ); //0=default, -1=any camera, 1..99=your camera   
 cout << "capture: " << !capture << endl;
```

produces

```
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
capture: 0
```

plus it hangs. According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393818/opencv-waitkey-not-responding-and-runtime-vidioc-querymenu-invalid-argument) this means that opencv and my webcam do not like each other.

I kind of like the whole opencv framework. For python I can easy get the camera using the pygame framework also cheese doesn't seem to have any problems with it. Is there something small lightweigt for C/c++ to simply get the picture and transform it into a Mat for opencv postprocessing? Or is there a way to fix this using opencv? I use ubuntu with 3.8 Kernel if it matters.

Comment: did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337913/problems-using-webcam-in-python-opencv ???

Comment: Wow, that's why I love StackOverflow. An answer within 13 min. Thank your for help